# react: достучаться до родителя компонента или передать данные от родителя к потомку

Tags: javascript, reactjs, наследование, компоненты

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно в такой схеме

```
render()
{
    return (
<Parent>
    <Child1>
    <Child2>
</Parent>
    );
}
```

на стороне компонент `Parent` и `Child` получить данные, которые будет сформированы в методе `render()` или в конструкторе

Понятно, что один из способов - передать в `props`, а если без этого?

Например устанавливается некоторое состояние, в конструкторе `Parent` получается это состояние родителя и устанавливается такое же свое состояние, в конструкторе `Child` получается состояние `Parent` и устанавливается свое состояние. В результате по всему дереву передаётся некоторый параметр.

Но чтобы такое реализовать нужно как-то получить доступ к родителю компонента.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать Context API. Подробнее по данной теме можно почитать [тут](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

https://codepen.io/smolinpavel/pen/MROJvo

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const defaultValue = { val: 2007, updateVal: () => {} };
const ValContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);

class Parent extends Component {
  static contextType = ValContext;
  render() {
    const { updateVal } = this.context;
    return (
      <>
        <h1>These are my children:</h1>
        {this.props.children}
        <h1>I am parent :)</h1>
        <button onClick={() => updateVal(1147)}>
          Make my children be born in 1147
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class Child1 extends Component {
  static contextType = ValContext;
  render() {
    const { val, updateVal } = this.context;
    return (
      <>
        <h2>child 1 was born in {val}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => updateVal(2055)}>
          Make us all be born in 2055
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class Child2 extends Component {
  static contextType = ValContext;
  render() {
    const { val, updateVal } = this.context;
    return (
      <>
        <h2>child 2 was born in {val}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => updateVal(2033)}>
          Make us all be born in 2033
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.updateVal = val => {
      this.setState({ val });
    };

    this.state = {
      val: 2019,
      updateVal: this.updateVal
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ValContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <Parent>
          <Child1 />
          <Child2 />
        </Parent>
      </ValContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Если интересно, можете также прочитать мою статью на похожую тему https://medium.com/comparethemarket/careful-switch-to-the-new-react-context-api-7021736a4bc8

Comment: огромное спасибо